# Timer time-out reset

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

I use a timer to draw animations, but I want the speed of the animation to change upon user input.

On the [API's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer), I read:

> A handle to the window to be associated with the timer. This window must be owned by the calling thread. **If a NULL value for hWnd is passed in along with an nIDEvent of an existing timer, that timer will be replaced in the same way that an existing non-NULL hWnd timer will be.**

I understood that I am supposed to call the `SetTimer()` function without the `hWnd` parameter to reset the timer, and so I did:

//function declaration

```
void InitiateTimer(HWND hWnd)
{
    SetTimer(hWnd,                          // handle to main window 
        IDT_TIMER,                          // timer identifier 
        1000 / Robot_Settings::getSpeed(),  // 1-second interval / speed 
        (TIMERPROC)NULL);                   // no timer callback 

    timerInitiated = true;
}

void ResetTimer()
{
    SetTimer(NULL,
        IDT_TIMER, 
        1000 / Robot_Settings::getSpeed(), 
        (TIMERPROC)NULL);
}
```

//function call in WindowProc

```
    case BUTTON_START:
        stopClicked = false;
        DestroyWindow(hStartButton);
        CreateStopButton(hWnd);
        if (!timerInitiated)
        {
            InitiateTimer(hWnd);
        }
        else if (timerInitiated)
        {
            ResetTimer();
        }
        return 0;
```

The idea was that on the reset, the timeout would be recalculated based on `Robot_Settings::getSpeed()`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't happen.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the docs.

To change an existing timer, you have to pass the same combination of `hWnd`, `nIDEvent` and `lpTimerFunc` arguments as when you initially called `SetTimer`.

From the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer):

> If the hWnd parameter is not NULL and the window specified by hWnd
>   already has a timer with the value nIDEvent, then the existing timer
>   is replaced by the new timer.

Also:

> The timer identifier, nIDEvent, is specific to the associated window.
>   Another window can have its own timer which has the same identifier as
>   a timer owned by another window. The timers are distinct.

The last quote alone is proof enough that you always have to specify the `hWnd` parameter to modify an existing timer that is associated with a window. Otherwise, how should the system know, which timer do you want to change? You could have two windows, each with a timer ID of 1, which are two distinct timers!